# Save Inputs from VBA Form to First empty row in Table

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to take a set of inputs from my user, and save it into a running list of all data collected.
This involves looking for the next available row to save it to, without overwriting previous points.

Here is what I have tried, but it is not working.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
LastRow = ws.Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
With ws
.Range("A" & LastRow) = DateInput.Value
.Range("B" & LastRow) = RedInput.Value
.Range("C" & LastRow) = WhiteInput.Value
.Range("D" & LastRow) = BlueInput.Value
.Range("E" & LastRow) = OrangeInput.Value
End With
```

Comment: `LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row`